# How to avoid copying referenced assemblies with new PackageReference xml tag in csproj

Tags: c#, visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

In C# project (SDK based project) I have following xml tag:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="log4net" Version="2.0.8" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

When building projects - `log4net.dll` gets also copied to output folder.
How to prevent that from happening ?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this xml tags does that one:

```
    <PackageReference Include="log4net" Version="2.0.8">
        <ExcludeAssets>runtime</ExcludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
```

Full documentation resides here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files

But it's maybe not so obvious.

If you want to cherry-pick what .dll's to copy from referenced package and which not to copy - at the moment it's not possible, see following open ticket: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5986